# Monthly alignment of multiple daily time series

Tags: pandas, time-series, date-range

So I have this dataset containing sales data for `N` items between day `d1` and day `d2`. For each purchase, I have the time stamp, the customer ID and the item ID. My goal is to generate a dataframe of size `(M x N)`, where `df[ i, j ]` is the total number of purchases for item `j` during month `i`.

Generate mockup data

```
import pandas as pd
import random

d1 = '2014-1-1'
d2 = '2014-3-31'
daily = pd.date_range( d1, d2, freq='D' )
npurchase = 1000
nitem = 20
olddf = pd.DataFrame( { 'dt': [ random.choice( daily ) for _ in xrange( npurchase) ], 'itemID': [ randint(nitem) for _ in xrange( npurchase ) ] } )
olddf.head()
```

Output:

```
                  dt    itemID
0   2014-02-24 00:00:00  19
1   2014-01-29 00:00:00  0
2   2014-01-27 00:00:00  7
3   2014-02-03 00:00:00  12
4   2014-01-24 00:00:00  3
```

Resample and align

```
rng = pd.date_range( d1, d2, freq='M')
newdf = pd.DataFrame( index=rng )

for name, group in olddf.groupby( 'itemID' ) :
    tmp = group.groupby( 'dt' ).size().resample( 'M', how='sum' )
    newdf[ name ] = tmp

newdf.fillna( 0, inplace=True )
newdf.ix[ :, :5 ]
```

Output

```
             0  1   2   3   4   5
2014-01-31   15  21  25  17  10  14
2014-02-28   10  13  16  20  15  8
2014-03-31   12  25  14  14  26  12
```

Is there a more efficient / elegant way to do it?

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you include some sample data. Obviously you won't want to share the financial data you have, but you could mock some up with random numbers that are similar in kind to your actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is 2.5x faster and 4x more elegant than my initial try:

```
olddf[ 'ones' ] = 1
newdf2 = olddf.set_index( 'dt' ).groupby( 'itemID' )[ 'ones' ].resample( 'M', how='sum' ).unstack( 0 )
print newdf2[ range(5) ]
```

Output

```
itemID       0   1   2   3   4
dt                            
2014-01-31  10  21  19  23  15
2014-02-28   8  11  12  20  11
2014-03-31  21  18  13  12  18
```

Comment: alternatively, one ca use pandas.pivot_table() http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html  combined with unstack() , e.g. I use it to turn a daily time series into a table years in columns, each month is a row, values are averaged of daily values for the corresponding month